# How to find the shortest distance of a point outside of a polygon starting at the polygon's edge?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, sqlgeography

Consider the following:

- Point **A** `DbGeography` (office address)
- Point **B** `DbGeography` (customer's address outside of office's service area)
- Polygon **C** `DbGeography` (office's service area)

Using the above points and polygon, how can I find the closest distance of **B** to **C**'s edge? I assume that first I need to find the line between **A** and **B**, then find where the line intersects **C** (= **D**) and then calculate the distance from **D** to **B**?

Since my usage of SQL Server's spatial capabilities is limited and I'm using Entity Framework, I'm not sure how to express that in code. I also assume that I'd have to use `SqlGeography` for this since `DbGeography` is kind of limited. I'd probably end up writing an extension to `DbGeography`.

I'd appreciate any suggestions (would love code examples) of how I can accomplish the above task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after messing around with this for the past three hours, I found a solution. Here's the code for anyone who cares:

```
public static class DbGeographyExtensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a double? value containing the shortest distance from the edge of this polygon to the specified point
    /// </summary>
    public static double? ToShortestDistanceFromPoint(
        this DbGeography polygon,
        DbGeography point) {
        if ((polygon != null)
            && (point != null)) {
            /// Convert the DbGeography to SqlGeography
            SqlGeography sqlPolygon = SqlGeography.STPolyFromText(new SqlChars(polygon.AsText()), polygon.CoordinateSystemId);
            SqlGeography sqlPoint = SqlGeography.STPointFromText(new SqlChars(point.AsText()), point.CoordinateSystemId);

            /// Get the shortest line from the edge of the polygon to the point
            SqlGeography shortestPoint = sqlPoint.ShortestLineTo(sqlPolygon);

            /// Return the length of the line (distance returns 0 because it excludes the area of the line)
            return (double?)shortestPoint.STLength();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need SQL Server 2012+ for the ShortestLineTo method